# How can I add a dictionary variable as a value in the same dictionary

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to make a combat RPG style game. I'm using dictionaries and I want to use a variable as a value in the same dictionary, an example below:

```
hero = {"name": "player",
        "lvl": 1,
        "plvl": lvl,
        "xp": 48,
        "N_lvl": 48,
        "stats": {"HP": 250,
                  "Att": 1,
                  "U_Att": [21,44],
                  "Def": 2}}
```

I want the value `plvl` to equal `lvl` but I cant find anything on the internet on how to do this. Also, I cant use another dictionary because it clashes with my program and it wont work the way I want it too if I were to do it.

Comment: You question is very unclear. Can you provide more context or a better description of what you are trying to do?

Comment: The op just wants to use a dict value for one key `lvl` as a 'backup' value for another key `lvl`. The wording might be off but I think the way he's trying to initialize the dictionary indicates his problem. Yes, he probably could've tried to state this in a better way.

Comment: Please excuse my wording, ill try and make my problems (titles) much clearer in the future, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to get at it in a single step; break it down in two: initialize and assign. First you initialize your dictionary:

```
>>> hero = {"name": "player", "lvl": 1, "xp": 48, "N_lvl": 48,
        "stats": {"HP": 250, "Att": 1, "U_Att": [21,44], "Def": 2}}
```

and *then* add the new `plvl` key to it and assign it the value contained in the `lvl` key:

```
>>> hero['plvl'] = hero['lvl']
```

The you'll have both in the same dictionary.

```
>>> hero
{'N_lvl': 48,
 'lvl': 1,
 'name': 'player',
 'plvl': 1,
 'stats': {'Att': 1, 'Def': 2, 'HP': 250, 'U_Att': [21, 44]},
 'xp': 48}
```

No need to complicate things.

---

The only other way to do this would be by defining `lvl` beforehand and using an alternate way of constructing a dictionary using the built-in `dict`:

```
lvl = 1
hero = dict(name = "player", lvl = lvl, plvl = lvl, xp = 48 ....) # and so on..
```

Comment: ah! Thank you very much! it works perfectly now. Big thanks!

Comment: @NileRedpath if this solved your problem don't forget to mark it as accepted for other users facing a similar issue to see. :-)